# onInput argument failure (by Elm n00b)

Tags: elm

I am experimenting with Elm based on their [tutorial](https://guide.elm-lang.org/architecture/user_input/forms.html), and is encountering a problem with function argument declaration.

Basically I just extracted a function within the tutorial code. It works fine without function declaration, but fails when I include it.

The essence of the code is:

```
type Msg
  = Name String
  | Password String

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div []
    [ myInput "text" "Name" Name
    ]

myInput : String -> String -> Msg -> Html Msg
myInput type__ label handle =
  input [ type_ type__, placeholder label, onInput Name ] []
```

And the error message is:

---

The 3rd argument to function `myInput` is causing a mismatch.

47|       myInput "text" "Name" Name
Function `myInput` is expecting the 3rd argument to be:

Msg

But it is:

String -> Msg

Hint: It looks like a function needs 1 more argument.

---

Ideally I would also like the argument to onInput be the argument called "handle", declared in myInput.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type signature for `myInput` is incorrect. The constructor `Name` has a single argument, which means when used as a function its signature is `(String -> Msg)`. That is what you should use for the annotation of the `handle` parameter.

```elm
myInput : String -> String -> (String -> Msg) -> Html Msg
myInput type__ label handle =
    input [ type_ type__, placeholder label, onInput handle ] []
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed to make this work, and to learn about data constructors and [Custom Types with Payloads](http://elmprogramming.com/type-system.html) Thanks!